# How to store docker images in Nexus OSS

Tags: nexus, n3dr

[The following documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5412197) was found that indicates that:

> simply create a new docker (hosted) repository as documented in
>   [Repository Management](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Repository+Management)

The problem is that the format docker seems not to be available when trying to configure a "Hosted repository"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nexus 2 was deployed instead of Nexus 3. The docker feature seems to be introduced since Nexus 3.

[This blog](http://blog.sonatype.com/using-nexus-3-as-your-repository-part-3-docker-images) indicates how to configure a docker repository and how to push and pull docker images.

The blog contains multiple pictures. The following picture indicates how to enable the docker registry:

[image]